# AngularJS: Create new scope variable name using a variable value

Tags: angularjs

I would like to create a new scope variable using the value of a variable passed to a directive's attribute. Just as an example, say we have a simple directive like this:

```
<div testme field="fieldval"></div>

.directive("testme", function () {
    return {
        template: "<div id='testme'></div>",
        link: function (scope,elem, attrs){
            $("#testme").html("Hello "+attrs.field);
        }
    }
})
```

The output is of course the value of the 'field' attribute:

Hello fieldval

However, what I want to do is create a new scope variable called $scope.fieldval, where fieldval is actually the value passed into the attribute 'field'

Any ideas?

Comment: The scope is just an object, you could just take the value and name a key on the scope like the input value.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer: pretty obvious really!!

```
scope[attrs.field] = "Some value";
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plunker, according to my comment:

http://plnkr.co/edit/FVm1PR0KPImp7pajdCN3?p=preview